# Как исправить переполненный поток?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
import stream from "stream";
import { promisify } from "util";
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

let gen = () => {
    return new stream.Transform({
        transform: (chunk, encoding, done) => {
            console.log('chunk');
            return done(null, chunk);

        },
        final: (onFinish) => {
            console.log('final');
        },
    });
};

let a = gen();

async function fn() {
    const readable = new stream.Readable()

    readable._read = () => {}
    readable.push(new Buffer(64)) //Так работает, вижу "final"
    // readable.push(new Buffer(64000)) //Так не работает, вижу только "chunk"
    readable.push(null)

    await pipeline(readable, a)
}
fn()
```

Есть такой код. Когда в transform отправляю 64 байта, все ок, он успешно завершается и я вижу "final". Когда 64000 - нет. Как это исправить? Как вывести "final" при переполнении потока?

Comment: думаю, это - слишком синтетический кейс применения. напиши `await pipeline(readable, a, process.stdout);`, чтоб Transform было с чем работать, и увидишь свой final

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало. А почему так? То есть если много чанков, то есть final а если один - то нет?

Comment: не знаю. я могу предположить, что это связано с последовательностью изменений состояний потоков и вызова колбеков в электронных мозгах ноды. т.е. по простому: "final" не "не вызывается", а "слово final не успевает напечататься".

Comment: Вообще я пытался тестить через setTimeout, после pipeline, - ничего не было. А в оригинальном сценарии у меня было: `await pipeline(axios.get('тут ссылка на картинку'), sharp, transfrom, fs.createWriteStream);`

sharp - библиотека.

И тут такой момент, когда убираю sharp - все работает. Когда добавляю, write - да, а трансформ нет.

Нашел это:
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1928

Comment: Заметил, что, если подписаться на событие "pause", то при 64000 поток становится на паузу.

`a.on('pause', () => {
    console.log(1);
});`

Comment: https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/ Только теперь не могу понять, как заставить работать